# Discarding extraneous characters in the stdin stream buffer

Tags: c, scanf

I want to write a function to read data from `stdin`. This function is to be called by other functions to prompt user to enter data.

```
void read_data(void) {
    // prompt the user by printing a message
    // printf("enter data:\n");

    int a;
    char name[40];
    scanf("%d", &a);

    // prompt for input again

    scanf("%39[^\n]", name);

    // do something with the data
}
```

In order for the function `read_data` to work correctly, there should not be any extraneous characters in the `stdin` stream buffer, i.e., it should be empty. The function doesn't know what was entered in the last `scanf` call and there may be integers and chars lying around in the input buffer.

How do I make sure that the function read_data works correctly?

Comment: Just use `fgets()` and read the input line by line. Much better (incl. safety!) than `scanf()`.

Comment: wouldn't subsequent calls to `fgets()` run into the same problem? What if the input string is longer than the buffer we pass to `fgets`? Next `fgets` call will start reading from the `stdin` buffer.

Comment: `fgets()` eats all trailing newline. If you pass a bugger of size `LINE_MAX`, then it's guaranteed to be able to hold any line.

Comment: I hope you meant buffer ;) So a foolproof way of reading a line of input from the `stdin`is `char line[LINE_MAX]; fgets(line, LINE_MAX, stdin);`? Then I can safely process `line` without messing with the `stdin` buffer.

Comment: Buffer, of course :) Yes, as far as I know, `LINE_MAX` is an implementation-defined macro that indicates that there should be no lines longer than that many characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
void read_data(void) {

 // prompt the user by printing a message
 // printf("enter data:\n");

 int a,c;
 char name[40];
 scanf("%d", &a);
 while((c=getchar()) != '\n');
 // prompt for input again

 scanf("%39[^\n]", name);
 while((c=getchar()) != '\n');
 // do something with the data
}
```

Use first scanf with

```
  while((c=getchar()) != ' ' && c != '\t' && c != '\n');
```

So if the given character is '\n' then the getchar function get the character and check whether it is new line if it is new line if move to further else it get upto newline so the stdin stream buffer is cleared.

Comment: the first `scanf` call will silently read from the buffer if there are non-white space characters without prompting the user for input.

Comment: and what if the input buffer is empty? Then you have to enter a whitespace char just to exit the while loop.

Comment: For what the input buffer of string is empty or number is empty